# TypeError: a.DataTable is not a function; coming from angular-datatables.min.js

Tags: angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables, total.js

I am trying to add angular-datatables for tables in my website;
The website is made with `total.js`

Datatable is not working and this error is coming:

```
angular.js:14642 TypeError: a.DataTable is not a function
    at Object.f [as renderDataTable] (angular-datatables.min.js:6)
    at Object.g [as hideLoadingAndRenderDataTable] (angular-datatables.min.js:6)
    at Object.f [as render] (angular-datatables.min.js:6)
    at angular-datatables.min.js:6
    at angular.js:17000
    at m.$digest (angular.js:18182)
    at m.$apply (angular.js:18480)
    at l (angular.js:12501)
    at XMLHttpRequest.s.onload (angular.js:12655) "Possibly unhandled rejection: {}"
```

This is the order of scripts

```
  <script src="@{global.js}"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/angularjs-social-login@2.6.1/angularjs-social-login.min.js"></script>

 <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-datatables/0.6.2/angular-datatables.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where do you have a script tag for angular? I mean something like `<script src="angular.min.js"></script>`